# Weird falling vertex glitch in 3.0/3.6

Tags: vertices

OK so I decided to get the latest Blender version to make it easier to follow tutorials while I start working on some assets for a game I want to eventually make. I already have to jump through hoops just to get the dang program to launch in the first place but this glitch is making it impossible to use. Any time I add loop cuts or try to fill in faces or make literally any changes the vertices "fall off" their positions all the way down to the origin.

[image]
[image]

Also I can't seem to add faces with the F key like I'm supposed to, it just does the vertex glitch thing instead. I can't select them and I can't avoid this happening. I can only ctrl+z to undo it.

[image]

I've tried switching in and out of object/edit/sculpt mode. I've tried saving and restarting everything. Why is this version of blender so unusably glitchy and how to i make it stop??? I can't make character models if the program won't let me add new faces or if the mesh keeps falling apart at every single action.

Comment: Edit: the same glitch happens in 2.90 as well. i don't know if this project file is just corrupted or something or if any version after 2.79 is just THAT broken because the only version i can use at this point that doesn't do this nonsense is 2.79

Comment: Edit 2: it doesn't happen on 2.8 thankfully, until this issue with 2.9-3.6 is resolved I'll just use 2.8

Comment: If the glitches you're showing in your images had been happening due to a bug in Blender they'd have been fixed in 2.9! Similarly with installing and running any version of Blender. No-one else is seeing them so there's nothing to fix in Blender. It's got to be a problem with your PC or  OS!

Comment: @JohnEason I suspected as much. this old beater is a hand-me-down from a former coworker after all LOL. Thankfully 2.8 has been working like a dream for me and seems to have basically the same features, interface, and controls as the newer versions. I appreciate hte help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You have both the Mirror modifier and the X symmetry option activated (top right ofthe 3D View), disable the X symmetry option.